# Link to static css file not working while using flask on vs code

Tags: html, css, flask, visual-studio-code, cs50

I have the following html code which I am using in Flask in VS code IDE.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <title>Final Project</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="container-xl pt-3">KeepTyping</h1>

  <main>
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
  </main>

  <!-- jQuery & Bootstrap Bundle  -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

But the CSS link below the meta tags doesn't work somehow and no styles are loaded into my html file. Even my internal styles done within the html file stop when I include the link. But, When I copied all the files into CS50's online IDE, it worked fine along with the styles. So I think there is some issues with running this on VS code's IDE.

I tried using href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}" as well as href="/static/syles.css". It worked both the times on CS50's IDE but none of the times on VS code. Am I doing anything wrong for VS code? [Here is the screenshot of my VS code project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRmKV.png)

Comment: Krupal, a good thing to check when using developing html templates is the source generated on the page (Ctrl-u). ie- is the `url_for` rendering literally? Also click on the link generated in the tag to see if it follows to the actually css file. Are you just opening the html file? and not serving it through a terminal?

Comment: That's really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am on VS Code. I have updated your `index.html` file and I am able to access `styles.css`

```html
<!-- layout.html remains as is -->



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}" />

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <title>Final Project</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 class="container-xl pt-3">KeepTyping</h1>

  <main>
    {% block main %}{% endblock %}
  </main>

  <!-- jQuery & Bootstrap Bundle  -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And now the `index.html` template

```html
<!-- index.html -->


{% extends 'layout.html' %}

{% block main %}
    <h1>Test SO</h1>
    <p class="test">
        this is a test
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

I have inherited the `layout.html` file using the keyword `extends`

I pass a test style in `styles.css`:

```css
/* static/styles.css */


.test {
    background-color: red;
}
```

I have also created a file called `.flaskenv` which has all the flask environment variables. These variables are needed by flask to run the server. It is located on the same location as the `app.py` file:

```py
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_DEBUG=True
FLASK_ENV=development
```

To load these environment variables, I installed `python-dotenv` package in my virtual environment:

```py
(venv)$ pip3 install python-dotenv
```

That is all for the package. You do not need to initialize it in your application.

In `app.py`, I have:

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In the terminal, I run this command to start the flask server:

```py
(venv)$ flask run
```

And this is the result:

[image]

So the styles get applied in the child template. Feel free to modify it as you please.